# HTC Evo 3D - Autosteroscopic camera image + OpenGL overlay

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, overlay, android-camera

We use a HTC Evo 3D and we are trying to get a 3D overlay (a cube drawn with OpenGL ES) in autostereoscopic mode over the also autostereoscopic drawn preview image of the camera, but we could not get it to work. What we can do is to have the camera view (either 2D or 3D) or we can have the OpenGL cube in 3D mode, but when we try to combine both things, either the whole device freezes (with "*W/SharedBufferStack(11043): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=425, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.*") or we only see the camera image but no overlay.

For the freezing thing we already read some information on the web and it seems that there is no real solution but patching the kernel so we are focussing on the other issue at the moment. 
So what we have is a `S3DGLSurfaceView` that extends `GLSurfaceView` and we enable 3D support by calling

```
Surface surface = holder.getSurface();
formatResult = DisplaySetting.setStereoscopic3DFormat(surface,
                      DisplaySetting.STEREOSCOPIC_3D_FORMAT_SIDE_BY_SIDE);
```

and on this view we draw our cube (which works perfectly, when we only add this view to our activity). But then, we also have a `CameraPreview` object which encapsulates a `Surfaceview` that we give to the stereoscopic camera by calling

```
camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_STEREOSCOPIC);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
```

where holder is stored from `preview.getHolder()` with `preview` being our `SurfaceView`.
For the activity itself we use a `RelativeLayout`, first add the camera preview and afterwards the OpenGL-surface - we also tried it the other way round but that does not change anything. We also tried to experiment with the z-order but this had also no effect.

Currently, our idea is that it is simply not possible to have two views that both have autostereoscopic mode enabled (the camera preview which has it automatically and our OpenGL surface where we enable it manually) but we have the hope that this is wrong and we miss something else.

It would be great if anyone could give us a hint how we can have a 3D overlay over the 3D camera image - so both in autosterescopic mode.